# accessing the contents of a List

Tags: c#

I've got multiple `List<string>` objects (1 for each column of a database) that I add all the data of a column to except the initial record when using the data reader.  How do I access these other elements?  Does it work like an array where I can just cycle through a 0-index and step up 1 to get the next element of the list?  Is there anyway to search these by element??

Comment: Please show a little code and some more explanation. I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: I am afraid not its just concatenating

Comment: If you have a list of strings then what's the problem?

Comment: Could you please post code so we can help you?

Comment: Thank you for posting the clarification, with `List<string>` you can step through it like any array `myList[i]`.  Or better yet, use `foreach (var item in myList)`.  BUT  If you are filling lists from each column in your database, why not just use `DataTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is used for string concatination. Once you concatinate two strings together, it is imposible to determine where one ends and other starts.

It seems that you could use `List<string>`. Then you can do something like this:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Hello");
list.Add("World");

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

UPDATE:

It seems that you have something similar to this:

```
var list1 = new List<string>();
var list2 = new List<string>();
var list3 = new List<string>();

using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

    while( rdr.Read() ) {

        list1.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
        list2.Add(rdr.GetString(1));
        list3.Add(rdr.GetString(2));
    }
}

//iterate through saved lists
for(int i=0; i<list1.Count; i++)
{
    var c1 = list1[i];
    var c2 = list2[i];
    var c3 = list3[i];
    Console.WriteLine(c1 + " " + c2 + " " + c3);
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize until reading your answer that I am actually using 8 `list<string>` is there any other way to search the list by element like an array possibly?

Comment: You can access list elements just like it would be an array. Just use index `var a = list[0];`

Comment: @Tim Perhaps you don't realise this yet, but you can edit questions. You should do so to make the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
StringBuilder
    sb1 = new StringBuilder(),
    sb2 = new StringBuilder(),
    sb3 = new StringBuilder();

using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

    while( rdr.Read() ) {

        sb1.AppendLine( rdr.GetString(0) );
        sb2.AppendLine( rdr.GetString(1) );
        sb3.AppendLine( rdr.GetString(2) );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but according to the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `StringBuilder`, it's possible to look at specific characters with the `Chars` property, or you can call `ToString()` on it and look in that string for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, StringBuilder doesn't have that sort of utility.

I suggest you assemble your "string" in a List first, and then concatenate them when you're finished, using Join.  If you do it that way you can access any "column" you wish simply by accessing an element of the array.

For example

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Column0");
list.Add("Column1 that references Column0 (which contains '" + list[0] + "')");
string finalString = string.Join(",", list.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder isn't designed to allow access to each individual operation against it.  Its purpose is to alleviate the performance problems with large quantities of string operations.  In C#, strings are immutable, so a large number of string manipulations can leave you with a large number of String objects which have implicit overhead.

If you need to access the entries in a data structure in an indexed manner you could look at something like:

```
 List<String> if you don't know the exact length in advance

 String[]  if you do know the length in advance
```